# Is MERGE syntax in BigQuery are scan entire tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I using `MERGE` syntax to entire table using two table, the source and the target. The task is to update old data in target and add new data from source in selected time (there's modified_time scan ). The problem is, i don't want the merge to scan entire rows and only focused on what i want to merge.

So I try to used this query:

```
  target trg
USING
  source src
ON
  trg.id = src.id
  AND trg.c_ctr = src.c_ctr
  AND DATE(trg.pt) = DATE(src.pt)
  AND DATE(trg.pt) >= "2019-12-12
WHEN 
  MATCHED AND DATE(src.pt) >= "2019-12-12 THEN 
UPDATE
  SET (...)
WHEN 
  NOT MATCHED AND DATE(src.pt) >= "2019-12-12" THEN
INSERT
  (...) VALUES (...)
```

When I try this query... it seems consume "pretty low" data (approx. 140MB) due i want to check from 25 days ago. I haven't try this query in big size tables. That something that i want to ask is, if i have give some condition to barrier the scan, is MERGE operation keep scan the entire table or just several rows covered by the partition? Any help are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe i should clarify and justified the question, is how merge works? Is it scan entire rows when do merge query or only scan rows that meet the conditions (ex: partition time)?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the documentation:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

> **DML pricing for partitioned tables**
>
> If there are only INSERT clauses in the MERGE statement, you are charged for the sum of bytes processed for all the columns referenced in all partitions scanned by the query.
>
> If there is an UPDATE or DELETE clause in the MERGE statement, you are charged for the sum of the bytes processed for all the columns referenced in all partitions for the source tables scanned by the query
>   + the sum of bytes for all columns in the updated, deleted or scanned partitions for the target table (at the time the MERGE starts).

The key part is `for all the columns referenced in all partitions for the source tables scanned by the query`. So if your filters scan only a few days of data, those filters will make sure your query will only be charged for those days.

Comment: so, it mean that the scanned rows is all rows from target which meet the partition, the source for update and insertion. it means let says i have 200 column in target, 100 meet the partition clause and also need updated. From source there's 200 rows and there's 120 rows from source that meet the partition, it means there only 100 scanned rows from target plus 120 rows from source. Am I right?

Comment: "the sum of the bytes processed for all the columns referenced in all partitions for the source tables scanned by the query"  plus "the sum of bytes for all columns in the updated, deleted or scanned partitions for the target table"